# Help with carpenter ants

Tags: pest, ants

I have noticed an increasing number of carpenter ants wandering in our house and a few days ago there were many winged-ants ( *very large, presumably queens or reproductive variety* ) on our property and generally around the neighborhood.

The outbreak of winged ants only lasted one day then they vanished. I have sprayed the perimeter base of the house and a few feet up the walls with bifen twice ( *about two weeks apart* ).

Even after spraying I saw numerous ants in the attic and I know this is a recent development as I have been up there a lot lately for electrical work/lighting installation.

While there is more than the random worker ant, I have not found enough to trace back to the colony.

Any advice on how to treat the problem?

Comment: I have a friend that works for a major pest company. on his recommendation he treated one of my places with a spray only pros can get in Oregon. The stuff is supposed to last 10 years he gave me a really good price, I don’t know what it was but I never saw another ant after a week , there is also some to put around ICF blocks as the ants love to nest in the foam, after fighting carpenter ants on my own and spending a small fortune the treatment would have been well worth full price.  You may be able to get it in your location but I really don’t remember the name but he had a full chemical suit